# Recursive call in Jess rule engine

Tags: jess

I'm trying to implement the transitive closure in Jess.

With

```
(deftemplate P
    (slot id)
    (multislot d) ; reference to Ps
)
```

How can I collect the transitive slot calls : (p::P).d.d.d.d.... until no more d-ref can be taken ?

I thought about

```
(deffunction closure(?p)
    ?p1 <- (P (id ?p) (d $?p1d) ; Get the fact which name is given as parameter
    ?p2 <- (P (id ?id&:(member$ ?id ?p1d))) 
    (union$ ?p closure( ?p2 ) ) ; Meaning p.d.d.d.d.d.d.d.d.... Tree wise.
)
```

but it doesn't give anything interesting.
I also thought about using queries, but since the call will be made from a LHS, I've been discouraged from doing so.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Edouard

Comment: What kind of graph can be represented by a set of P facts? If it is a tree (an acyclic graph), a recursive function would be preferable to a set of rules. (Implementing such algorithms using rules is not impossible, but why?) - For a general graph, you'll have to mark nodes. Processing this would be more in favour of using rules, but, again, functions should be easier.

Comment: Well, it is not by definition a tree. But that is close to the point : I want to make generic rules that ensure there's no cycle (or that a certain property is achieved (or not) once a cycle is found). Generic, to be reuse and encapsulated. I would use a function, or even a query, I'm trying hard to..

Comment: You should be able to find an algorithm for locating cycles in a graph. The implementation might use rules, but I'd prefer functions. Google.

Comment: Finding an algorithm is a first step, and locating cycles (greedily) is pretty straight forward. But remember Jess doesn't allow recursive calls implying complexe constructs. I guess because there's no infrastructure to pattern-match them.

Comment: "Recursive rules" isn't doable, at least not with the implementation technique used by Jess and Drools (and a few other rule engines). If this needs to be done in Jess, use functions - Lisp is just the language for recursion. -- Note that many graph algorithms aren't recursive, so using rules with these wouldn't be a problem. I have implemented Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm in Jess - entirely in rules.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration and attention. Is it possible to have a look at the Dijkstra algorithm in Jess ? I'd be interested to see that :) I will for now try to resolve a few other weackness on my project and I'll get back to that part with some distance - it helps usually. Thanks again.